# c# windows form Filtering using RadioButton

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

Can any one tell me how to filter the Datagridview based on selected radio button, i have attached a screenshot of the form I created, need to filter based on deposit and withdrawal. I have taken TransactionType as enum.

[image: Screenshot of form]

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the rows in your DGV and check if the first cell value = value (Deposit/Withdrawal/Both depending on which RadioButton is checked), then set

```
DataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `DataSource` according the selected radio button.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
grid.DataSource = bs;
```

By changing your radiobutton selection

```
bs.DataSource = q;
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

for q use:

1. `var q = Transactions`
2. `var q = Transactions.Where(t=>t.TransactionType==Deposit)`
3. `var q = Transactions.Where(t=>t.TransactionType==Withdrawal)`

Answer (score 0):

A code that does what you want would look like this: (probably not the right variable names)

1. Check value which radio button is checked
2. according to which one is checked, read column"transactionType" of each row,
3. render visible or not the rows you want.

---

```
Foreach(DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
  if(radioButtonDeposit.isChecked())
  {
    if(row["TransactionType"].Value == Enum.Deposit)
    {
       row.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       row.Visible = false;
    }
  }
  else if(radioButtonWithdrawal.isChecked())
  {
    if(row["TransactionType"].Value == Enum.Withdrawal)
    {
       row.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
      row.Visible = false;
    }
  }
  else 
    row.Visible = true;            
}
```